# How to set FTP session idleness timeout in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ftp, timeout

I have a Ruby thread that first connects to a FTP server and then uploads thousands of files over. Due to some connection issues, the Ruby thread often hangs. So I want to set a timeout for the ftp idleness.

The post [Ruby Net::FTP Timeout Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230172/ruby-netftp-timeout-threads) suggests using the Timeout module:

```
begin
  Timeout.timeout(10) do
    // connect to FTP and upload
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
    ...
end
```

This approach won't resolve my issue, because the timeout is for the whole computation block, rather than the timeout starting from the idleness/inactivity of the FTP session.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
transferred = 0
buffersize = 1024
filesize = File.size(file)
ftp.putbinaryfile(file, "/private/transfer/#{File.basename(file)}", buffersize) { |data|
  raise "no data sent" if data.size == 0 or data.size < buffersize
}
```